# Problem with a OneToMany connection in DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

GitHub - rostyF/bankingProjectDemo

I work with api bank. It returns the following result:

```
 {
                "date":"01.12.2014","bank":"PB","baseCurrency":980,"baseCurrencyLit":"UAH","exchangeRate":
                [
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"CHF","saleRateNB":15.6389750,"purchaseRateNB":15.6389750,"saleRate":17.0000000,"purchaseRate":15.5000000},
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"EUR","saleRateNB":18.7949200,"purchaseRateNB":18.7949200,"saleRate":20.0000000,"purchaseRate":19.2000000},
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"GBP","saleRateNB":23.6324910,"purchaseRateNB":23.6324910,"saleRate":25.8000000,"purchaseRate":24.0000000},
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"PLZ","saleRateNB":4.4922010,"purchaseRateNB":4.4922010,"saleRate":5.0000000,"purchaseRate":4.2000000},
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"SEK","saleRateNB":2.0283750,"purchaseRateNB":2.0283750},
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"UAH","saleRateNB":1.0000000,"purchaseRateNB":1.0000000},
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"USD","saleRateNB":15.0564130,"purchaseRateNB":15.0564130,"saleRate":15.7000000,"purchaseRate":15.3500000},
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"XAU","saleRateNB":17747.7470000,"purchaseRateNB":17747.7470000},
                    {"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"CAD","saleRateNB":13.2107400,"purchaseRateNB":13.2107400,"saleRate":15.0000000,"purchaseRate":13.0000000}
                ]
            }
```

According to this json, I created two classes (entities) Result and ExchangeRate. Logically, we have a One To Many connection, so I placed the annotations accordingly.
As a result, for some reason, we have a strange result.
The result_id column contains null , although it should have had an ID attached to result(1).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlxuJ.png)

Also, for some reason, in the same table, the id starts with 2, not 1.
Please explain what I did wrong, maybe I misunderstood something. Many thanks in advance!

```
@Entity
public class Result {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String date;
    private String bank;
    private Integer baseCurrency;
    private String baseCurrencyLit;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "result", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@OrderColumn(name = "array_index")
    //private ExchangeRate[] exchangeRate;
    private List<ExchangeRate> exchangeRate;

    public Result() {
    }
```

```
@Entity
public class ExchangeRate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String baseCurrency;
    private String currency;
    private Float saleRateNB;
    private Float purchaseRateNB;
    private Float saleRate;
    private Float purchaseRate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "result_id")
    private Result result;

    public ExchangeRate() {
    }
```

```
public class Main {
    static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    static EntityManager em;
    private static final String NAME = "bankingTest";
    //static int id = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?date=01.12.2021");

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            Result res = gson.fromJson(getInfo(url), Result.class);

            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(NAME);
            em = emf.createEntityManager();

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(res);
            long id = res.getId();
            em.getTransaction().commit();



            em.close();
            emf.close();





        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }
    public static String getInfo(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        con.disconnect();
        return content.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: `gson.fromJson(getInfo(url), Result.class);` I assume that `fromJson()` does not call `ExchangeRate#setResult()` and therefore hibernate doesn't insert the ID there. As for the ID starting with 2, its probably how the database is set up

Comment: oh yeah. My solution:
 Result res = gson.fromJson(getInfo(url), Result.class);
            List<ExchangeRate> list = res.getExchangeRate();
            for(ExchangeRate exchangeRate : list){
                exchangeRate.setResult(res);
            }
            res.setExchangeRate(list);

It works